# GAPI PHP, total visits, changed?

Tags: php, google-analytics

Sorry to revive the topic, but I have the same doubt.

I am using the gapi, currently "10/23/2013" google changed a bit how to get the data. I can not get the total visits.

I just need the total number of visits to my site, nothing more.

Here the code I'm using:

```
<?php
define('ga_email','email@gmail.com');
define('ga_password','password');
define('ga_profile_id','999999');

require 'gapi.class.php';
$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,
  array('browser','browserVersion'),
  array('pageviews','visitors')
);
?>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Browser &amp; Browser Version</th>
  <th>Pageviews</th>
</tr>

<?php
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $result ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo "Visitors: ".$result->getVisitors() ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
    endforeach
?>

</table>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Total Results</th>
  <td><?php echo $ga->getTotalResults() ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Total Pageviews</th>
  <td><?php echo $ga->getPageviews() ?>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Total Visits</th>
  <td><?php echo $ga->getVisitors() ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Results Updated</th>
  <td><?php echo $ga->getUpdated() ?></td>
</tr>

</table>}
```

Can someone get me an example of how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your foreach is wrong

```
<?php
 ....

 foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
?>
```

must be like this :

```
<?php
 ....

 foreach($ga->getResults() as $result) {
 ?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $result ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo "Visitors: ".$result->getVisitors() ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
 }
?>
```

What do you get with :

```
<?php
....


$ga->requestReportData(
  ga_profile_id,
  array('browser'),
  array('pageviews','visits'),
  array('-visits'),
  null,
  '2013-05-01',
  null,
  1,
  30
);
?>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Total Pageviews</th>
  <td><?php echo $ga->getPageviews() ?>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Total Visits</th>
  <td><?php echo $ga->getVisits() ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, based in your answer i made correct code, if anybody needs i put  the code here, i made some modifications and other inclusions.